# Использование метода likes.isLiked для объектов вне стены пользователя

Tags: вконтакте

Столкнулся с небольшой проблемой. Нужно проверить, есть ли объект (пост) в списке "Мне нравится" у пользователя. Если этот объект был опубликован на стене пользователя, то в `owner_id` передаем id странички этого пользователя, скажем, 12345. Но если этот объект был создан, скажем, в группе или в публичной странице, то как обычно id группы с дефисом выдают ошибку. Может, кто знает как быть?

Для наглядности примеры:

Работает

```
https://api.vk.com/method/likes.isLiked?access_token=токен&user_id=12345&owner_id=6789&type=post&item_id=33
```

Выдает ошибку:

```
https://api.vk.com/method/likes.isLiked?access_token=токен&user_id=12345&owner_id=-6789&type=post&item_id=33
```

Comment: Что самое интересное в методе likes.getList все работает замечательно как и в остальных. Получается баг или спецом закрыто...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Необходимо отрицательный параметр заключить в кавычки:

```
https://api.vk.com/method/likes.isLiked?access_token=токен&user_id=12345&owner_id="-6789"&type=post&item_id=33
```